# Hive XML Serde : Parsing error when loading xml content

Tags: xml, parsing, hadoop, hive, hive-serde

I am trying to load the following XML content using SerDe with Hive :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RootTag xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.website.com/service">
<Code>123</Code>
<ParentElement>
   <Entity>
      <EntityId>A</EntityId>
      <EntityCode i:nil="true"/>
   </Entity>
   <Entity>
      <EntityId>M</EntityId>
      <EntityCode i:nil="true"/>
   </Entity>
</ParentElement>
</RootTag>
```

The hive table was created as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE database.mytable(
code   String, 
Entity array<struct<Entity:struct<EntityId:String,EntityCode:String>>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
(
  "column.xpath.Code" = "/RootTag/Code/text()",
  "column.xpath.ParentElement" = "/RootTag/ParentElement"
)
STORED AS 
INPUTFORMAT  'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION     '/xml_content/'
TBLPROPERTIES ("xmlinput.start" = "<RootTag", "xmlinput.end" = "</RootTag>");
```

I have 2 issues:

1. when I specify the "xmlinput.start" as specified above, it doesn't work. I had to remove manually the content "xmlns:i = ... /service" next to the "RootTage" in order to start parsing the xml.
2. Even though, there is another issue with "EntityCode" attribute. I am getting the error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:
  java.io.IOException:
  org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: 
  java.lang.RuntimeException:
  org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
  lineNumber: 41;
  columnNumber: 33;
  The prefix "i" for attribute "i:nil" associated with an element type "ParentCode" is not bound.
```

What am I doing wrong? I would appreciate your suggestions and comments regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things.

- I think the root tag with namespace is only supported on **version 1.5.0.3** or greater. check the following link https://github.com/dvasilen/Hive-XML-SerDe/issues/15
- I am don't think it supports the `i:nil="true"`
- Mapping of column should match the column name and it's case sensitive. `column.xpath.Code` and `code` won't work. Also there is no corrosponding column for `column.xpath.ParentElement`

**So what you need to do?**

- Upgrade your serde.
- replace `<EntityCode i:nil="true"/>` to `<EntityCode/>` in your xml
- Fix the code as mentioned below

**Code**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE temp.test_xml(
code   String,
Entity array<struct<Entity:struct<EntityId:String,EntityCode:String>>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
(
  "column.xpath.code" = "/RootTag/Code/text()",
  "column.xpath.Entity" = "/RootTag/ParentElement/Entity"

)
STORED AS 
INPUTFORMAT  'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION     '/tmp/test_xml1/table/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
                "xmlinput.start"="<RootTag",
                "xmlinput.end"="</RootTag>");
```